# how to call a function to load an array in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am reading values from json file. I created a sample json file.

```
contact.json:
  [
   {
     "id":"1",
     "Name":"abc"
   }
  ]
```

I created a service class

```
ContactsService.
    app.factory('ContactsService', function ($rootScope, $http, $log) {
        var contacts = [];
        return {
            getContactsList: function() {
                return contacts;
            },
            loadContactsFromJson: function () {
                var promise = $http.get('json/contacts.json')
                    .success(function(response) {
                        contacts = response;                    
                        return contacts;
                    })
                    .error(function(response) {                 
                        contacts = [];
                        return contacts;
                    });
                    return promise;
            }
        };
    });
```

In my controller class:

```
 init();
 function init() {       
   ContactsService.loadContactsFromJson();       
 }
 $scope.contactsList = function() {
   return ContactsService.getContactsList();
 };
```

but here `contactsList` is a function but I am trying to create an array `contactlist` in my controller class and trying to load the array in `init()` function. Later for the click event i want to add more contacts to this `contactlist( contactlist.push)`. How do I read values from  `ContactsService.getContactsList()` method to an array variable instead of function?

Comment: So you want to use `$scope.contactlist` that is link to array instead of '$scope.contactsList()' that actually returns it?

Comment: yes. if I am using $scope.contactList( later I cannot push objects in to it. I tried to assign in to an array $scope.contactlist = [] and in init method  $scope.contactlist = ContactsService.getContactList(); but did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create public variable (property of `Service`) and then just link `Controller` to it.

```
//Service
return {
    ...
    contactsList: []
    ...
}
```

and in `Controller`:

```
//Controller
$scope.contactsList = ContactsService.contactsList;
```

Comment: Either just do `contactsList: contacts` for less refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can let the promises you've set up do the work for you. Try something like this in the controller:

```
ContactsService.loadContactsFromJson().then(function (contacts) { 
  $scope.contactsList = contacts;
}
```

If you wanted to I suppose you could wrap that in your init function. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript objects are passed by reference. However when you do `contacts = response` inside a function copy of the reference is created and the initial reference is broken (call-by-reference), thus the changes made to the `contacts` variable are not applied to `$scope.contactList`.

Try doing smt. like `contacts.push['test']` inside success function to see it yourself.